# Variable observations disappear after merging

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm pretty new to R and have a professor who is only providing examples and not much explanation, so I'll do my best to explain my problem.

I used `randomizr` to create an experiment.

```
set.seed(20016)
```

```
A <- complete_ra(N = 9954, m_each = c(3318, 3318, 3318), conditions=c("Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Control"))
```

```
table(A)
```

Then I was to show a distribution of the treatments on the existing data, separated by gender. So I followed example work to make and new data set with the treatment, calling the new variable "gender" so I could then merge with the existing data...

```
gender <- seq(1.9954)
```

```
new_gender <- data.frame(gender, A)
```

```
final_data <- merge(colombia, new_gender, by.x = "gender", all.x = TRUE)
```

This all seemed well and good but now when I view final_data, variable A is all full of N/A. When I would view it in the new_gender data set all the observations were filled out with assignments of "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Control" but now that's gone. Where did my observations go? My goal is to graph it like this:

`ggplot(final_data, aes(x = A)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = gender)) + labs(title = "Treatment Separated by Gender", x = "Treatment", y = "Count")`

But I only get one bar right now instead of three because variable A is all "N/A"s.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am at a total loss...

Comment: What sequence were you looking to generate here: `seq(1.9954)`?

Comment: It was a sequence of the number of observations in the data set. So it just went 1,2,3,4,5,6...and then the treatment/experiment was applied. I hope this helps sorry I'm not super clear on what I'm doing

Comment: Is it possible to see a subset of your data?